# Passing in a destructured object?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

```
const FlatListBasics = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={[
          {key: 'Devin'},
          {key: 'Dan'},
          {key: 'Dominic'},
          {key: 'Jackson'},
          {key: 'James'},
          {key: 'Joel'},
          {key: 'John'},
          {key: 'Jillian'},
          {key: 'Jimmy'},
          {key: 'Julie'},
        ]}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
      />
    </View>
```

So today while reading the React Native docs I came across this bit of code where we are essentially passing in a `{item}` as destructured.
I did read up on destructuring a bit and I know how it works but I don't understand how we are passing it in to the function as destructured and why we are doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand how we are passing it in to the function as destructured

It's not being **passed in** destructured. It's being destructured *on receipt*, by the function. This code:

```
renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
```

sets `renderItem` to a function. The function accepts a parameter, using destructuring to pick out its `item` property. It's just like this:

```
renderItem={(obj) => <Text style={styles.item}>{obj.item.key}</Text>}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why: they're doing it likely to just reduce the noise of accessing properties on objects.

```
renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
// could also be written as
renderItem={(props) => <Text style={styles.item}>{props.item.key}</Text>}
```

How: if you understand destructuring, you understand the how: it's essentially using syntax sugar to pluck values off objects in the parameters rather than later on in the function body.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of flatlist, where item is part of the props being passed into the render function.

```
 renderItem={(props) => console.log(props)}
```

By using the above, you can see what's inside the render props. item is just part of it.

If you don't deconstruct, then you have to use `props.item` instead of `item`.